# Gravity form error: "Are you sure you want to do this?"

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity form plugin (version 2.2.1.6) in Wordpress (version 4.7.4).
When trying to access the settings -> confirmation and notifications of my form I get this error message : "Are you sure you want to do this?"

I tried to desactivate/activate all my plugins, the error is still the same.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks for advise,